# How to show full Python Traceback with Tox/Py.test

Tags: python, pytest, tox

I'm using tox and py.test to run my Python unittests, and even though I'm using py.test's `--tb=long` option, errors are showing like:

```
E   ConftestImportFailure: (local('/myproject/tests/functional_tests/conftest.py'), (<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>, ImportError('No module named blah',), <traceback object at 0x7fb5bb740518>))
```

Tox is running the command:

```
py.test -rxs -rf -rs --ff --tb=long -x -k testname
```

How do I make is show the full traceback? I can't find anything mentioning this in the docs besides the `--tb` option.

Comment: It looks like error happening inside conftest, where you trying to import module, which is not importable. Try `py.test -vvs --pdb -k testname` and this should drop you into `pdb` prompt to debug. (I know this works for tests, not 100% sure it will work for conftest).

Answer (score 8):

For pytest, you can use `py.test --tb=native` to switch to the full/native Python tracebacks.

See [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/output.html#modifying-python-traceback-printing) on tracebacks.

Answer (score 0):

by putting a `{posargs}` or `[]` into the command invocation, you can run `tox -- --full-trace`

a ConftestImportFailure tends to point to another mistake as well, their reporting is worse tho

Comment: I am getting a > tox: error: unrecognized arguments: --fulltrace

Comment: indeed, a dash was added in a iteration